# Оформление нумерованного списка с союзом «и»

Tags: пунктуация, и, оформление-текста, список

Можно ли так графически оформить текст?

Мне нужен диапазон саксофона-альта:

1) фактический

и

2) по написанию.

Союз "и" стоит между пунктами списка. Корректно ли это? Необходима ли после первого пункта точка с запятой?

Comment: Бытует вариант, широко применяемый именно в научной литературе: «Нужен диапазон саксофона-альта (1) фактический и (2) по написанию».

Answer (score 1):

Хотя само по себе не красиво, но если очень надо так сделать, то только не на одной строке с первым пунктом. Вы когда-нибудь видели запятую или скобку сразу после союза? Союз всегда примыкает к СЛЕДУЮЩЕЙ, а не к ПРЕДЫДУЩЕЙ части фразы. Поэтому либо ставьте его между пунктами, либо включайте во второй пункт.

Что касается точки с запятой, то её рекомендуют ставить только в том случае, когда пункт очень длинный и содержит собственные, внутренние знаки препинания. В коротких нужно ставить запятую, а пункты писать со строчной буквы (или точки, но писать с прописной).

Но, учитывая, что у вас есть союз, то запятые, точки с запятой и точки после пунктов невозможны. Запятая возможна лишь в случае, если у вас будут последующие пункты, начинающиеся с того же союза. Получатся однородные союзы, которые можно (и нужно!) будет разделять запятыми. В противном случае возникает простейшая для русского языка ситуация выбора: запятая или союз. В вашем случае выбор отдали союзу. Причём в том случае, когда следовало ставить запятую. Все проблемы вашего примера именно в том, что вы отдали предпочтение не тому языковому инструменту, которому следовало. Уберите "и", поставьте запятую, и тогда этот отрывок не будет вызывать вопросов. Если смысл теряется, то перефразируйте, либо просто обойдитесь без списка. Всё же два пункта это не так уж и много, чтобы применят список. Ну а пока только так.

Comment: В таком случае можно будет в первом пункте поставить точку с запятой?

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вот что имеется в [справочнике Мильчина](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F/):

> **Между элементами внутриабзацного перечня ставят:**
>
> а) запятую, если элементы простые (из нескольких слов, без знаков препинания внутри); например:
> *Обратить внимание: а) на правильность, б) однородность, в) целесообразность.*
>
> б) точку с запятой, если элементы содержат много слов, со знаками препинания внутри; например:
> *Ниткошвейные машины по степени автоматизации выполняемых операций делятся на следующие виды: 1) полуавтоматы (с ручной подачей тетрадей в швейное устройство и ручным выполнением некоторых других операций); 2) автоматы (с автоматической подачей тетрадей и программным управлением).*

Вот что имеется на "Грамоте" (["Как оформлять перечни?"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/83-rubric-77)):

> Со строчной буквы начинается текст каждого элемента в перечне, если ему предшествует цифра со скобкой:
> *1) новое и старое;*
> *2) старое и новое.*

В саксофонах ничего не понимаю, но предлагаю такие варианты, если уж так нужно оформить предложение в виде списка (союзу "и" в нем нет места).

*Мне нужен диапазон саксофона-альта:

1) фактический,

2) по написанию.*

*Мне нужен диапазон саксофона-альта: 1) фактический, 2) по написанию.*